# how to convert some mysql into pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, database-administration

Can somebody help me convert this into PDO

```
// verify email and password pair
$userid = 0;
$query = sprintf("SELECT id FROM users WHERE LOWER(email)='%s' AND passwordhash='%s'",strtolower($email),$pwdhash);
$resource = mysql_query($query);
if ($resource)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($resource);
    if (isset($row[0]))
        $userid = $row[0];
}
```

This is my attempt:

```
$userid = 0;
$resource = $dbh->query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE LOWER(email)=':email' AND passwordhash=':hash'");
$resource->bindValue(':email',$email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$resource->bindValue(':hash',$pwdhash,PDO::PARAM_STR);
if ($resource->execute())
{
    $result = array();
    while ($row = $resource->fetch()) {
        array_push($result, $row);
    }

    if (isset($result[0]))
    $userid = $result[0];

    $dbh = null;
    return $result;
}
```

I am pretty sure something is wrong with the part inside the if statement

And other attempt:

```
    $userid = 0;
    $resource = $dbh->query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE LOWER(email)=':email' AND passwordhash=':hash'");
    $resource->bindValue(':email',$email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $resource->bindValue(':hash',$pwdhash,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    if ($resource)
    {
        $row = $resource->fetchAll();
            if (isset($row[0]))
            $userid = $row[0];
    }

    // close database and return 
    $dbh = null;
    return $userid;
}
```

There was few more attempts...

Comment: $dbh->prepare instead of $dbh->query i think.

Comment: replace `query` with `prepare` and remove the single quotes around `:email` and `:hash`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

Use `prepare` rather than `query`, the result of a prepare is a statment handle which can be used to bind values to the named parameters you have used in the prepare.

```
$userid = 0;
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE LOWER(email)=:email AND passwordhash=:hash");
$stmt->bindValue(':email',$email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':hash',$pwdhash,PDO::PARAM_STR);
if ($stmt->execute())
{
    $result = array();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        array_push($result, $row);
    }

    if (isset($result[0]))
    $userid = $result[0];

    $dbh = null;
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: does it mean i cant bind values to the parameters inside query handle

Comment: No you cannot. `$dbh->query()` issues the query directly to the database so there is no point where you can amend parameters. So its basically for simple queries that have no requirement for parameters or where the parameter can be hardcoded like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 = 10`